Is there a story in Mahabharat where a woman comes to Vidur telling her husband's illness and Vidur consulted Kundali and finding her lover she had?
Long time back on this website I remember reading a comment (which is now deleted) that there is a story described in Mahabharat where a woman comes to Vidur telling him about her husband's illness.
Vidur then saw the Kundali of the wife, and found that the husband should have been died long back.
He got surprised as to how her husband is alive, when he should have died according to her Kundali.
On that Vidur inquired and found that the woman had a "relationship" with some other man prior to marriage. So, technically the man was the husband of the woman (Gandharva Vivah), and not the man she socially married to. And that man has died according to Kundali.
I want to know this story in detail. And what was the nature of the relationship of the woman with her lover.
